# special words prediction in dx-text-area

Tags: angular, autocomplete, devextreme

I need to autocomplete special words when writing message in dx-text-area
I've tried to add dx-auto-complete in dx-text-area it works for first word only how can I make it predict for each word starts with #
this is my code

```html
            <dxi-item dataField="message" editorType="dxTextArea">
                <div *dxTemplate>
                    <dx-autocomplete (onEnterKey)="drop($event)" 
                    [dataSource]="['#111','#222', '#444']">
                    </dx-autocomplete>
                </div>
                <dxo-label text="Message"></dxo-label>
            </dxi-item>
```

and this is the result
[image]

when I try to add # after text the dropdown menu does not appear

Comment: can you please post the drop($event) code on your question?

Comment: it has only console.log to print the event

Comment: it is filtering data by what you entered in the input field. For example, if you press # it will return all words starting with #. Then if you enter #1 it will return only #111.

Comment: searchMode
Specifies a comparison operation used to search UI component items.

Type: String
Default Value: 'contains'
Accepted Values: 'contains' | 'startswith'